# Need to setup an office network, suggest some hardware?

Tags: networking, router, switch, windows

We have 6 windows workstations, spread out over a fairly large area. Need to share a DSL connection (upgrading to 100/100 mbit fiber in a few months) with these machines over a 1gbit network. Also need Wifi to be available for laptop use.  Plan to add 2 rackmount servers for internal use as well.

Can someone suggest a decent (preferably low cost) setup that will let me achieve the stuff mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't let the router/firewall throttle your 100/100 fiber.  Options:

- **Low-end:**  pfsense and old PC(s), 2 Netgear GS-108 @ $45 ea after rebate (unlikely both die at once), Linksys WRT-54GL @ $50 (add free DD-WRT firmware if you like, and a better antenna if coverage requires)
- **Higher:**  Cisco ASA-5505-50-Bun-K9 @ $500, Cisco Linksys E4200 WiFi @ $180, Netgear GS-116E smart switch (Windows-app-managed) @ $195 OR Cisco's new SLM2016T-NA (web-managed) @ $275
- **My Preference:** Cisco [RV220W-A-K9-NA](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/routers/ps9923/ps11025/data_sheet_c78-630461.html)  Gig/Firewall/VPN/WiFi @ $270, Netgear GS-116E @ $195

Comment: A pfSense box with an 800MHz-1GHz CPU with 512MB RAM and Intel or 3com NICs should manage a 100Mbps connection at wire speed just fine.  Gigbit is a different story, but if you've got a gigabit WAN link you likely won't be beige-boxing it for a firewall.  +1 for the other recommendations, RV220W is a great small-office unit with a lot of features built in.

Comment: What about something like PROSAFE WIRELESS-N VPN FIREWALL
SRXN3205 instead of the Cisco? Any good?

Comment: Newegg's commenters say the SRXN3205 VPN client won't do Win 7, if that matters.  The RV220W is VERY new, with IPv6, a fast Cavium CN5010 CPU, 1 yr phone support, SNMP mgt, 2.4 OR 5 GHz (not concurrent).  I like the beta notes at http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r25397964-H-W-NEW-CISCO-RV220w-Network-Security-Firewall

Comment: Yah, we use win 7, so that counts that one out. On the Cisco, 2.4 or 5.0 is a bit of an issue also. Beh.

Comment: Well, if it's enough of an issue to be worth $50, use the Cisco for 5.0 and pick up a WRT-54GL for 2.4.  Remarkably solid, especially with the classic version of DD-WRT.

Comment: You can connect another wifi router to it, and create another SSID?

Comment: Yes. Check the 5GHz coverage in your office before deciding you need it (data rates fall off fast w/distance).  But the RV220W lets you swap antennas, so easy to extend.  One thing:  If you host a public website behind it, and want internal PCs to reach the site by its public name, you'll want to use PC hostfiles or another DNS workaround until future firmware gives you NAT loopback.

Answer (score 1):

Does "spread out over a fairly large area" still mean the same physical office or building?  If so, I'd suggest you put a second NIC in an old, unused desktop or server box and install [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) as a WAN/gateway to share the DSL line.  It's extremenly easy to install and configure and has a very intuitive web management interface.  Depending on your business/security requirements you can either plug this directly into you LAN switch or create a [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) with any outward-facing resources (web hosting, email, VPN, etc.) that you need to host yourselves.  A second pfSense "beige box" would then separate your LAN from the DMZ.

If you plan to add a wireless access point to your LAN , ensure it supports up-to-date connection encryption (WPA2) and secure this and the admin access to the WAP device BEFORE you deploy.

Comment: No, they're on the same floor, just scattered over 3 different rooms. Running cables is not an issue.

Comment: Good, then the above should apply :)

Comment: Make sure the cables are terminated carefully, use Cat5e or better for all components.  Wiring problems are worth avoiding.

Answer (score 0):

I would be hesitant to advise a homebrew box if you don't have in-house expertise with the free OSes and related hardware. You can definitely do wonders with even a cheap PC running either an appliance-style Linux/BSD install or a homespun environment.

I would consider a Juniper SSG5 or SSG20 with wireless, along with a 16-24 port gigabit switch. I think the routers would run you around $500... you can add a license for antivirus/antispam/IDS type features if you want.

Another option would be Cradlepoint's MBR1200, which will let you do multiple connections (use the DSL as a failover for the 100mbit connection) and back that up with USB cellular modem (Verizon, Clear, AT&T, whatever). You also get 802.11b/g/n. It's probably about $300. (I've used an MBR800 and MBR1000 myself)

Comment: Can't speak to Juniper, but having worked with both pfSense and Cisco, for example, I certainly don't think pfSense is any more difficult to install or configure than getting an ASA or Pix up and running.  Your point is taken for a *real* homebrew setup using iptables or pf directly, but web-managed appliances like smoothwall or pfSense are really pretty simple to set up.

Comment: Setting up is fine, but the concern I'd have is when something goes wrong. They can probably get commercial support if the internal staff don't have networking expertise. As long as nothing goes wrong, either way should work fine.